# How to create a Primary Key composed of fragments of other fields? - MySQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I want to create a table where the Primary Key will be composed of fragments of other fields if it's possible.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS movie (
    title VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    director VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    genre VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    year DATE,
    duration INT NOT NULL,
    description TEXT,
    movie_key VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
    PRIMARY KEY (movie_key)
);
```

For example, I have a movie:

Title: Forrest Gump
Director: Robert Zemeckis
Genre: Drama
Year: 1994
Duration: 140

and I want that this movie's movie_key be: FGRZDr1994

*FG (title initials)
*RZ (director initials)
*Dr (genre)
*1994 (year)

Comment: A combination of string functions should be sufficient - do you have a specific problem. AND where are you inserting the information from?

Comment: And... how it could be? I am using workbench, at the moment I don't have data inserted, it was just an example of how the structure would be

Comment: This strikes me as a bad idea. If you later find an error in the data (even just a typo, or the wrong year or something) and have to update it, then this will change the primary key. This then a) creates the possibility of a clash with another record, b) makes any other data or external records which relied on this ID incorrect, and now they can't find the data. An ID must be guaranteed not to change, otherwise it's useless.

Comment: Furthermore, it's theoretically possible (even if not very likely in reality) that you could have a problem where two movies have enough similarity in their data (e.g. they happen to have the same initials, same director initials, same genre and year) that they would end up with the same value for the primary key. And then you would not be able to enter them both in the table at once because it would violate the key.

Comment: I would strongly advise you to use the conventional method and create an auto-increment integer field as the unique ID and primary key for this table. Then there's a guarantee there will be clashes, and the ID will definitely stay the same for the whole lifetime of the record, regardless of any updates to the fields. If you want to generate this movie_key as a calculated field, just as a more user-friendly reference number, then you could still do that as well, but with the caveat that it may change and may not be unique, so no-one should rely on it to refer to a particular movie.